quiver loops latex

How can i write this? I tried
\xymatrix@C=-.1pc{
1 \overset{a}{\to} & 2 \ar@(ur,dr)[]^b &
}

but it doesn't work

its look like this

This question is similar to: How do I label a loop arrow in tikz-cd?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

you have still not shown your input code,  nor any error message from the log, did you mean to tag this as xypic rather than tikz-arrows?

something like this?
\documentclass[border=3mm,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
    b & 1 \arrow[out=150,in=210,loop]  \arrow[r,"a"] & 2
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}



gave the same error again

put the error message in your question, please

i added @CrocoDuck

I am using the following codes, which one might be causing the problem? \usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,urlcolor=blue,citecolor=blue}
\usepackage[all]{xy,xypic}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb,amsmath,amsgen,amsopn,amsbsy,amsthm,graphicx,epsfig}
\usepackage{eufrak,amscd,bezier,latexsym,mathrsfs,enumerate,multirow}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

it worked fine on my PC. Which Latex are you using (texlive, miktex, overleaf, etc)?

@wanheda If you get an error, please edit your question and add a complete example. In this case it would be a not working one, but it should nevertheless be complete, starting with \documentclass and a preamble with (only) the preamble code and a \begin{document}…\end{document} needed to reproduce the problem. And and also copy&paste the exact error message from your `log'-file into the question. Use the code block markdown for the message to it shows the identical linebreaks.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\tikzcdset{
  quiver loop left/.style={left,out=-165,in=-195,loop,looseness=8},
  quiver loop right/.style={right,out=15,in=-15,loop,looseness=8},
}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=1.2em]
1 \arrow[r,"a"] & 2 \arrow[quiver loop right,"b"]
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\[
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=1.2em]
1 \arrow[quiver loop left,"b"] \arrow[r,"a"] & 2
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}



gave an error :(

@wanheda Not on my machine.

@wanheda If you get an error, please edit your question and add a complete example. In this case it would be a not working one, but it should nevertheless be complete, starting with \documentclass and a preamble with (only) the preamble code and a \begin{document}…\end{document} needed to reproduce the problem. And and also copy&paste the exact error message from your `log'-file into the question. Use the code block markdown for the message to it shows the identical linebreaks.
